# I am unable to run maven2

Tags: maven-2

I am not able to run Maven 2.1. I get following Error while running:

```
****************************************************************
naresh@HYRDSRVIHUB01:~/.m2> mvn  archetype:create -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'archetype'.
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins: checking for updates from central
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'org.apache.maven.plugins' could not be retrieved from repository: central due to an error: Error transferring file: Connection refused
[INFO] Repository 'central' will be blacklisted
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 22 17:59:02 IST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/240M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

******************************************************************
```

Help me to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, you **are** running Maven. However, depending on what you're asking Maven to do, Maven might have to download libraries from a *remote* repository: plugins, dependencies, etc that are then stored in your *local* repository and downloading libraries from a remote repository **requires** a connection.

If you start using Maven with an empty local repository, this is something you can't avoid and you'll have to let Maven download what it needs first.

Sure, you can run Maven offline (using the `-o` or `--offline` command line optionsbut this will work only if you already have the required stuff in your local repository.

Oh, and by the way, I'm not sure it's really wise to create a project under your `~/.m2` directory. You should run `archetype:create` from another location, e.g. `~/Projects`.

Comment: Even if i give -o option it results with same Error. Can you please help me Pascal

Comment: @gnash-85: I don't know what I can do for you. Running Maven without an Internet connection, or a corporate repository, or a pre-populated local repository (with all the limitation this implies) is not possible. What are your constraints exactly?

Comment: See I want to convert all ant scripts to Maven one. This is the task i was given. But Now I want to test maven whether it is working or not. But it fails initially only. So Pascal Sir, can you please help me.

Comment: @gnash-85: Ok, I get that. But did you read my comment? I gave you 3 possibilities to make things work. If none of them are an option, then I'm afraid you won't be able to use Maven. I don't have any magical solution, sorry.

Comment: Yes Pascal Sir. Now i have set-up some proxy settings and now it is working. Can you please how to convert from ant to maven?

Answer (score 0):

Your running maven, the issue is either with your connection it seems to be getting rejected by the maven repo:

[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'org.apache.maven.plugins' could not be retrieved from repository: central due to an error: Error transferring file: Connection refused

Comment: How to resolve it. I want to use to Local Repo instead of Maven Repo.
How to solve it?